# Creating a loop using spring-webflux and avoid memory issues

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I am currently working on a project where I need to create a loop using spring webflux to generate a Flux for downstream processing. The loop should sequentially take batches of elements from a source (in this instance a repository) and pass the elements as signal in a Flux. To acquire the elements, we have a repository method which fetches the next batch. When all elements have been processed, the method yields an empty List.

I have identified that I can use Flux::generate in the following manner:

```
Flux.<List<Object>>generate(sink -> {
  List<Object> batch = repository.fetch();
  if (batch.isEmpty()) {
    sink.complete();
  } else {
    sink.next(batch);
  }
})
...
```

However, when I use this, the argument method runs continuously, buffering until I run out of memory.

I have also tried using Flux::create, but I am struggling to find an appropriate approach. I have found that I can do the following:

```
Consumer<Integer> sinker;

Flux<?> createFlux() {
  return Flux.<List<Object>>create(sink -> sinker = integer -> {
    List<Object> batch = repository.fetch();
    if (batch.isEmpty()) {
      sink.complete();
    } else {
      sink.next(batch);
    }
  })
  ...
  .doOnNext(x -> sinker.accept(y))
  ...
}
```

Then I just need to call the Consumer initially to initiate the loop.

However, I feel like I am overly complicating a job which should have a fairly standard implementation. Also, this implementation requires secondary calls to get started, and I haven't found a decent way to initiate it within the pipeline (for instance, using .onSubscribe() doesn't work, as it attempts to call the Consumer before it has been assigned).

So in summary, I am looking for a simple way to create an unbounded loop while controlling the backpressure to avoid outOfMemory-errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I have found a simpler solution which serves my need. The method Mono::repeat(BooleanSuplier) allows me to loop until the list is empty, simply by:

```
Mono.fromCallable(() -> repository.nextBatch())
  .flatMap(/* do some stuff here */)
  .repeat(() -> repository.hasNext())
```

If other more elegant solutions exist, I am still open for suggestions.